# Find the value of $c$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1+ce^x}{\sqrt{1+cx^2}} = 4$

Tags: limits

Find the value of $c$ such that  $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1+ce^x}{\sqrt{1+cx^2}} = 4$$
I don't think if there exists such $c$, but don't know how to prove.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: Numerator ≈ exponential; Denominator ≈polynomial. limit $\to+\infty$.

Comment: yeah Nr: exp; and Dr;Quadratic; It seems function increases drastically
**Try** Nr/Dr > 4 from what value of $x$ and as this function must be increasing after since

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there exists no such value of $\color{red}{c}$ However, You can prove these types results by proving that it's independent of whatever parameters are mentioned there in the equation(In your question if you think there exists no such $\color{red}{c}$ then you simply need to prove it's independent of $\color{red}{c}$)

Also, We need to know only when $x\to\infty$

Here, I guess $c ≠ 0$ As this adds no meaning for applying limit and for $x\to\infty$ negative values of $\color{red}c$  will compel denominator to give complex roots but numerator will have negative sign only {$\frac{-ve}{a+ib} \in \mathbb C∉ \mathbb R ≠ 4  $ } can't be $4$(or Real)

**Conclusion:** We'll worry for only +ve values of $\color{red}c$ for which Numerator and denominator will tend to $\infty$ and we can use [**L'Hôpital's rule**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

$$\begin{align*}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1+ce^x}{\sqrt{1+cx^2}}  
& = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{ce^x}{\frac{2xc}{2\sqrt{1+cx^2}}}\\ \text{L'Hôpital's rule as type }\left(\frac{\infty}{\infty}\right)
& = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x\sqrt{1+cx^2}}{x}\\
& = \lim_{x\to\infty}e^x\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+\color{red}{c}}\\
& = \text{As, } x\to\infty \text{ limit of the function  } \to \infty \text { independent of } \color{red}{c}.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I wonder if you can be sure that c*e^x and c*x^2 will go infinity as x goes infinity.

Comment: @Snow_kafka Yes, You are right I had to mention that $c ≠0$

Comment: Thanks a lot 

Comment: @Snow_kafka In fact thanks to you I wonder if complex values will ruin the problem

Comment: @DarshanPatil No, even if you take negative values of $c$, you cannot get the limit to be $4$. The standard answer would be to say the limit will either not exist because the expression is not defined for negative values of $x$. If we expand $\sqrt{x}$ to be $i\cdot\sqrt{-x}$ for negative values of $x$, then the limit for negative values of $x$ is still not $4$.

Comment: @5xum Yes thanks!, It makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that such a $c$ doesn't exist. Here's how to prove it:

Notice that this limit only makes sense if $c$ non-negative; if $c<0$, then the expression $\sqrt{1+cx^2}$ would not be defined for every sufficiently large $x$, rendering the limit meaningless.

With this established, note that we can write

\begin{align}
\frac{1+ce^x}{\sqrt{1+cx^2}} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+cx^2}}+\frac{ce^x}{\sqrt{1+cx^2}}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+cx^2}}+\frac{c}{\frac{1}{e^x}\sqrt{1+cx^2}}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+cx^2}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{e^{2x}}\left(1+cx^2\right)}}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+cx^2}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{\frac{1+cx^2}{e^{2x}}}}\\
\end{align}

so if $c=0$, we have

$$\frac{1+ce^x}{\sqrt{1+cx^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+0}}+\frac{0}{\sqrt{\frac{1+0}{e^{2x}}}}=1$$

and thus the limit is $1$. If $c>0$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+cx^2}}\to 0$ and
$$\frac{c}{\sqrt{\frac{1+cx^2}{e^{2x}}}}\to\infty\text{ because }\sqrt{\frac{1+cx^2}{e^{2x}}}\to 0$$
so

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1+ce^x}{\sqrt{1+cx^2}}=\infty$$

Thus, the limit can never be $4$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is clear that if $c<0$, then the expression in the limit will be negative whenever $|c|e^x>1$ which happens whenever $x>-\ln |c|$.

It is also clear that if $c=0$, the limit is $1$.

For $c>0$, you can use the following estimate to see where the limit will go:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1+ce^x}{\sqrt{1+cx^2}} &= \frac{\frac{1+ce^x}{x}}{\frac{\sqrt{1+cx^2}}{x}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{1+ce^x}{x}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+c}}\\
&\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{c+1}}\cdot\frac{ce^x}{x}\\
&\geq \frac{c}{\sqrt{c+1}}\cdot \frac{e^x}{x}
\end{align}$$

After you do this estimate, you can use the fact that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x}{x}=\infty$$
which can be proven in a number of ways.

Answer (score 0):

$e^x=\Omega(x^3)$ so that your expression is $\Omega\left(\sqrt c \,x\right)$, which diverges. ($c=0$ is not a solution.)